# Adding my user to sudoers does not work. Still ask for password

Tags: sudo, password, visudo

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04

I made the mistake of editing /etc/sudoers with "vim" first instead of using "visudo".
Therefore when I was doing "sudo command" it kept asking for my password.
Then I tried to do "sudo visudo", retyped the line for my user, saved it. But it keeps asking for my password whenever I use "sudo command". 
What could be wrong?

System output:

```
$ grep alain /etc/sudoers
  alain ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

$ sudo -l

  User alain may run the following commands on wscg4:
  (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
  (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the user's line to an external file fixed it:

`$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myOverrides`

Comment: The user (alain) is probably also in the sudo group. And in the sudoers file you first define `user privilege specification` and then `allow members of group sudo to execute any command`. And so override your NOPASSWD.
By putting it in the sudoers.d folder, you override it again.